# Rational map on $\mathbb P^2$ whose each co-ordinate is monomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $\mathbb P^2$ be the Projective plane over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Is the rational map $f :\mathbb P^2 \to \mathbb P^2$ given by $f(x: y : z)=(x^2 : y^2: z^2) $ Birational ?

In general, if $f(x: y: z)=(f_0(x,y,z) : f_1(x,y,z) : f_2(x,y,z) )$ is a rational map on $\mathbb P^2$ where $f_i$ 's are non-zero  monomials of same degree with no common factor, then when can we say that $f$ is Birational ? What happens if all the $f_i$ are also square-free ?

Comment: No, your map $f$ is not birational but finite and $\deg f=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map in your example is regular and finite of degree 4, hence not birational.

If every $f_i$ is a monomial of degree $d_i = (d_{i0},d_{i1},d_{i2})$, the map is toric, in paricular it restricts to a group endomorphism of the algebraic torus 
$$
T = \{ x \ne 0, y \ne 0, z\ne 0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^2.
$$ 
In particular, it is birational if and only if the endomorphism is an isomorphism, i.e., if and only if
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix} 
d_{00} & d_{01} & d_{02} \\ 
d_{10} & d_{11} & d_{12} \\ 
d_{20} & d_{21} & d_{22} 
\end{pmatrix} = \pm d.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "degree" here ? Why is a finite regular map of degree 4 not Birational ? Could you please elaborate on this ... also what is your $d$ ?

Comment: If by degree you mean the degree of a surjective finite morphism, then I'm not sure whether my map is surjective or not ...

Comment: If $f$ is indeed finite (surjective) of degree $4$ then I can see why it is not birational, but I'm not sure why the degree is $4$ ? ... I think I can see surjective ... since the map is polynomial and injective, it is surjective by Ax-Grothe ..

Comment: $d$ is the degree of the monomials $f_i$. The map is surjective over the torus, hence dominant, hence (being proper) is surjective. The degree can be computed over the torus, and since there it is a group homomorphism, it is enough to compute the preimage of the point $(1:1:1)$, which consists of 4 points $(\pm1:\pm1:1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification ... and sorry to bother you again, but I can't figure out why is the map a finite map ? Could you please help ?